# how to call a camera activity to another activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I am doing an app that will let the imageButton to call a camera activity from my project capture an image and return the captured to the imageButton. My problem is I can't call the camera it keeps on getting all these errors.

ERRORS:

```
16:29:50.953: D/AndroidRuntime(644): Shutting down VM
08-10 16:29:50.953: W/dalvikvm(644): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bodapps.kinkytimefree/com.bodapps.kinkytimefree.Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.bodapps.kinkytimefree.Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.onCreate(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.java:150)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-10 16:29:51.003: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  ... 11 more
08-10 16:29:55.024: I/Process(644): Sending signal. PID: 644 SIG: 9
```

CODE:

```
package com.bodapps.kinkytimefree;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu extends Activity 
{







    //Spinners for Players
//  public Spinner spinner_1;
//  public Spinner spinner_2;
//  public Spinner spinner_3;

    //TextView for Players
    public TextView player_1;
    public TextView player_2;
    public TextView list_label;
    public Animation fade;

    //SFX
    public static MediaPlayer game_signal, BG;

    //Intent
    public Intent next_intent;

    //Button to Start
    private Button play_it;

    //For Displaying Text
    public String SUMMON_PICK_UP_1, SUMMON_PICK_UP_2, SUMMON_PICK_UP_3;

    //Integers
    public int waited;

    //Text Response from a Spinner
    public final static String EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_1 = "com.bodapps.kinkytime.LABEL_2_1";
    public final static String EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_2 = "com.bodapps.kinkytime.LABEL_2_2";


    private static final int GET_CODE = 0;

    //public ImageView image1, image2;
    public ImageButton image1, image2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.players_3);

        //Setting the typeface. Put it before finding the ID of the text.
        Typeface type_face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/MA Sexy.ttf");


        //TextView Initialization
        player_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_1_spinner);
        player_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_2_spinner);
        list_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        play_it = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_GAME);


        //Typeface Settings
        list_label.setTypeface(type_face);
        player_1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        player_2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);


        //Getting proportional size according to the screen resolution to get the right dimension.
        player_1.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2));
        player_2.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2));
        list_label.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize3));


        //Set the SFX
        game_signal = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.female_sigh_moan);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chill_out);


        //Play Sequence
        BG.setLooping(true); //No loop.
        BG.setVolume(22, 22); //Sets the loudness L/R.
        //BG.start();


        //Set intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        next_intent = new Intent(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.this, Loading_Screen_to_Game.class);


        //Searching for ID... (Button)
        play_it = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_GAME);


        //Edit Color for Buttons and Text Views
        play_it.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        play_it.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        play_it.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2));
        list_label.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);


        //Adding listener to the button(s).
        play_it.setOnClickListener(new trigger_happy_start());


        //Retrieve the message.
        SUMMON_PICK_UP_1 = intent.getStringExtra(from_3_players.EXTRA_MESSAGE_1);
        SUMMON_PICK_UP_2 = intent.getStringExtra(from_3_players.EXTRA_MESSAGE_2);


        //Display the retrieved names.
        set_info_1(SUMMON_PICK_UP_1);
        set_info_2(SUMMON_PICK_UP_2);


        //Set the text for the next activity (KinkyTimeActivity.java).
        String label_2_1 = player_1.getText().toString();
        String label_2_2 = player_2.getText().toString();
        next_intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_1, label_2_1);
        next_intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_2, label_2_2);


        //Set Animation
        fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fader);
        fade.setFillAfter(true);

        //images for the image avatar

        image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBoy);
        image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageGirl);


    }

        public void handleClick(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, Capture_Main_Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CODE);

        }

        public void handleClickOne(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(this, Capture_Main_Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, GET_CODE);
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == GET_CODE)
            {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            }

        }


    //public void onClick(View v)
        //{

        //Call camera after info has been set


            //switch(v.getId()){

            //case R.id.imageBoy:

                //startActivity(new Intent(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.this, Capture_Main_Activity.class));

                //break;

            //case R.id.imageGirl:

                //startActivity(new Intent(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.this, Capture_Main_Activity.class));

                //break;
            //}
             //return;

            //}



    //Set for Name of Player 1
    public void set_info_1(String player1)
    {

        player_1.setText(SUMMON_PICK_UP_1);

    }








    //Set for Name of Player 2
    public void set_info_2(String player2)
    {

        player_2.setText(SUMMON_PICK_UP_2);

    }








    private class trigger_happy_start implements OnClickListener
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //BG.stop();

            //Play Sequence
            game_signal.setLooping(false); //No loop.
            game_signal.setVolume(55, 55); //Sets the loudness L/R.
            //game_signal.start();

            //Logo played by the animation.
            player_1.startAnimation(fade);
            player_2.startAnimation(fade);
            list_label.startAnimation(fade);
            play_it.startAnimation(fade);

            Thread entering = new Thread()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    try
                    {
                        waited = 0;

                        while(waited < 3000) //Waits for 3.0 seconds.
                        {
                            sleep(100);
                            waited += 100;
                        }

                    }

                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        //Do nothing.
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(next_intent);;
                    }

                }

            };

            entering.start();

        }

    }       
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageGirl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/girl_6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="List of Players:"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player_1_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="empty"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player_2_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="empty"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/START_GAME"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:text="START GAME" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageBoy"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepicboy2" 
        android:onClick="handleClickOne"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageGirl"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_layout"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepicboy2"
        android:onClick="handeClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Camera Activity Code:

```
package com.bodapps.kinkytimefree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Capture_Main_Activity extends Activity 
{

    //Variables needed for the camera capture.
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String path;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //Camera Status
    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.capture_layout);

        //Array for the camera images.
        final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) 
            { 
                //Pick an image taken from the camera.
                if (item == 0) 
                {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                       "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);


                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);
        mImageView      = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo); //Checking for player one's image.

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                doCrop();

                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();

                break;          

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    //saveBitmapToFile("/sdcard/bodapps/cropped_img.jpg", photo);

                    //Place player's image here!
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                break;

        }
    }

    //private void saveBitmapToFile(String string, Bitmap photo) {

    //  File file = new File(path);
        //boolean res = false; if (!file.exists()) {
        //try {
        //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); res = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); fos.close();
    //  } catch (Exception e) { }
        //} return;
        //}

    //}

    private void doCrop() 
    {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) 
        {           
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot find image crop app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } 
        else 
        {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) 
            {
                Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } 
            else 
            {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) 
                {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");

                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) 
                    {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }

                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() 
                {
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) 
                    {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }

                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says you: ``android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton``.

Answer (score 0):

in the code part you have written

```
 image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageGirl);
```

but in the XML you have defined

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageGirl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/girl_6" />
```

Here you are casting an ImageView into an ImageButton which isnt allowed and is hence throwing the exception.

You should change the ImageView in the XML to ImageButton.

Comment: didn't see that sorry :) i removed it already. but it still wont call

Comment: i posted the errors here as well, its underneath i guess this message :) please look

Comment: now you are using the ImageButton and Button combination.
Both Have to be ImageButton for it to work.

Comment: what do you mean sir? cos i have one button for start game and 2 imagebuttons

Comment: isnt your code something like this?
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonname);
the initial part should also be ImageButton

Comment: image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBoy);
  image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageGirl); like this?

Comment: can you post your new code, editing the question and replacing the existing ones?

Comment: i've only change the imagebuttons code. please see again i posted it here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you use `ImageView` in xml and `ImageButton` in activity.
The error tells you not to cast `ImageView` to `ImageButton`.

Try changing it either in xml, either in activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.bodapps.kinkytimefree;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;   
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
//import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu extends Activity 
{







    //Spinners for Players
//  public Spinner spinner_1;
//  public Spinner spinner_2;
//  public Spinner spinner_3;

    //TextView for Players
    public TextView player_1;
    public TextView player_2;
    public TextView list_label;
    public Animation fade;

    //SFX
    public static MediaPlayer game_signal, BG;

    //Intent
    public Intent next_intent;

    //Button to Start
    private Button play_it;

    //For Displaying Text
    public String SUMMON_PICK_UP_1, SUMMON_PICK_UP_2, SUMMON_PICK_UP_3;

    //Integers
    public int waited;

    //Text Response from a Spinner
    public final static String EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_1 = "com.bodapps.kinkytime.LABEL_2_1";
    public final static String EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_2 = "com.bodapps.kinkytime.LABEL_2_2";


    private static final int GET_CODE = 0;

    //public ImageView image1, image2;
    public ImageButton image1, image2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.players_3);

        //Setting the typeface. Put it before finding the ID of the text.
        Typeface type_face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/MA Sexy.ttf");


        //TextView Initialization
        player_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_1_spinner);
        player_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_2_spinner);
        list_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        play_it = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_GAME);


        //Typeface Settings
        list_label.setTypeface(type_face);
        player_1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        player_2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);


        //Getting proportional size according to the screen resolution to get the right dimension.
        player_1.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2));
        player_2.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2));
        list_label.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize3));


        //Set the SFX
        game_signal = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.female_sigh_moan);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chill_out);


        //Play Sequence
        BG.setLooping(true); //No loop.
        BG.setVolume(22, 22); //Sets the loudness L/R.
        //BG.start();


        //Set intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        next_intent = new Intent(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.this, Loading_Screen_to_Game.class);


        //Searching for ID... (Button)
        play_it = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_GAME);


        //Edit Color for Buttons and Text Views
        play_it.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        play_it.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        play_it.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2));
        list_label.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);


        //Adding listener to the button(s).
        play_it.setOnClickListener(new trigger_happy_start());


        //Retrieve the message.
        SUMMON_PICK_UP_1 = intent.getStringExtra(from_3_players.EXTRA_MESSAGE_1);
        SUMMON_PICK_UP_2 = intent.getStringExtra(from_3_players.EXTRA_MESSAGE_2);


        //Display the retrieved names.
        set_info_1(SUMMON_PICK_UP_1);
        set_info_2(SUMMON_PICK_UP_2);


        //Set the text for the next activity (KinkyTimeActivity.java).
        String label_2_1 = player_1.getText().toString();
        String label_2_2 = player_2.getText().toString();
        next_intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_1, label_2_1);
        next_intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEXT_MESSAGE_2, label_2_2);


        //Set Animation
        fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fader);
        fade.setFillAfter(true);

        //images for the image avatar

        ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBoy);

        ImageButton image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageGirl);


    }

        public void handleClick(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, Capture_Main_Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CODE);

        }

        public void handleClickOne(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(this, Capture_Main_Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, GET_CODE);
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == GET_CODE)
            {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            }

        }


    //public void onClick(View v)
        //{

        //Call camera after info has been set


            //switch(v.getId()){

            //case R.id.imageBoy:

                //startActivity(new Intent(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.this, Capture_Main_Activity.class));

                //break;

            //case R.id.imageGirl:

                //startActivity(new Intent(Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.this, Capture_Main_Activity.class));

                //break;
            //}
             //return;

            //}



    //Set for Name of Player 1
    public void set_info_1(String player1)
    {

        player_1.setText(SUMMON_PICK_UP_1);

    }








    //Set for Name of Player 2
    public void set_info_2(String player2)
    {

        player_2.setText(SUMMON_PICK_UP_2);

    }








    private class trigger_happy_start implements OnClickListener
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //BG.stop();

            //Play Sequence
            game_signal.setLooping(false); //No loop.
            game_signal.setVolume(55, 55); //Sets the loudness L/R.
            //game_signal.start();

            //Logo played by the animation.
            player_1.startAnimation(fade);
            player_2.startAnimation(fade);
            list_label.startAnimation(fade);
            play_it.startAnimation(fade);

            Thread entering = new Thread()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    try
                    {
                        waited = 0;

                        while(waited < 3000) //Waits for 3.0 seconds.
                        {
                            sleep(100);
                            waited += 100;
                        }

                    }

                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        //Do nothing.
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(next_intent);;
                    }

                }

            };

            entering.start();

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: is START_GAME an image button?